# jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu Plugin Updates

Tags: wordpress, updates, compatibility, php-8

I am helping update a website that currently uses WordPress 6.2.2 and php 7.4 but I would like to update to WordPress 6.3 and php 8.0.

It has a lot of outdated plugins such as jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu and I was wondering if anyone knew the best method to updating this.

I was debating whether the best option is to switch to a new plugin that has been updated more recently, or if there was a way to update this one to ensure compatibility.

If the best option is switching to a new one, does anyone have any advice or recommendations?

I have looked at other plugins to update to, such as Max Mega Menus, but I was unsure if I could update everything correctly to it without losing original content on the WordPress page.

Comment: If the outdated plugins such as jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu, is discontinued (not anymore updated, with no active support), you may try to update the plugin directly if you don't find an easy replacement plugin. If the plugin is still updated, with a support, then open support thread. Anyway, all these processes are going to take you some time and effort, whatever you choose.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you! I have tried to update the plugin using Rector set to php 8.0, but I am not certain how reliable that is (also for checking that it matches WordPress 6.3 requirements). From what I can tell, I do not think it has been updated for a couple of years. I do not want to risk anything by updating the site and losing stuff if the plugin is not compatible, so maybe my best option is to switch to a newer plugin.

Comment: Anyway, you need to have a stage where site, where you will make all your changes and test them. Now, if this website works as it is, and the managers doesn't plan to add new features or strong changes, simply don't update the site as it seem to be a real time-consuming hard work. Only apply minor WP version security patches, and don't change anything, keeping the current server configuration.